# How to solve Source path does not exist: resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml

Tags: ionic-framework

I do build with ionic 4.

> ionic cordova build android

Got this error

> cordova build android
>
> Source path does not exist:
>   resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml [ERROR] An error
>   occurred while running subprocess cordova.

I removed this part from config.xml. Is it fine?

```
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
    </edit-config>
    <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
```

**package.json**

```
    {
      "name": "morenito",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "author": "Ionic Framework",
      "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~8.0.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "8.0.1",
        "@angular/material": "8.0.1",
        "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
        "@ionic-native/base64": "^5.5.1",
        "@ionic-native/base64-to-gallery": "^5.6.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.10.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera-preview": "^5.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^5.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.5.1",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.5.1",
        "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.5.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
        "browser": "^0.2.6",
        "cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.3",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "highcharts": "^7.1.1",
        "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
        "highcharts-more": "^0.1.7",
        "highcharts-more-node": "^5.0.13",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "ng2-charts": "^2.0.3",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
        "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.4.3"
      }

,
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

FOR VALIDATOR ONLY: Is it a stackoverflow or an art competition? Hello validator - you bother me day by day. This post contains enough of text.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Examine the resources folder if the xml folder exists in /android, if it doesn't just create it like..

```
resources/
    android/
        xml/
           network_security_config.xml
```

Enter the following inside the file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: I did the above mentioned fixes - but this was the straw that broke the camel's back for me. Thank you @Mr Strange :)

Comment: Life saver answer :) Works also for ionic 5.

Answer (score 3):

I also got that error check this

> https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/issues/758

in android platform  in ionic

```
<platform name="android">

<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
</edit-config>
<resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
```

Comment: For android@^8.1.0 make sure the target is correct: target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml"

Answer (score 2):

within your project: resources => android => create folder "xml" create file.xml:
**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>`
```

Answer (score 1):

H guys, I did have also this problem, my fix to It was, in config.xml remove this line `<resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />` and It works for me.